# How do I uninstall a NuGet package without deleting its folder?

Tags: nuget

I'm storing all my packages in `D:\Dev\Packages`, using the `repositoryPath` attribute value as documented [here](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.1#user-content-specify-packages-folder-location). However, when I uninstall a package from a VS 2015 project, the package folder is deleted as well. I need to retain the folder, as other projects in other solutions are using it.

This behavior has changed since VS 2013. As far as I can recall, package folders weren't deleted during uninstall. If they were I surely would have noticed it before now.

So: how can I make sure that the package folder isn't deleted during a package uninstall?

Comment: check it into source control? That way it can't be deleted without you OK'ing it, and if it is, you can always revert the commit (if it autocommits).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: That's a clear definition of the word *workaround*, stated twice ;-) Something more straightforward, perhaps? A checkbox option or command line switch somewhere? I've looked at the VS Tools\Options settings—of course—but nothing's showing up there.

Comment: The repositoryPath setting is used to configure the path that where the nuget packages been installed, so when you uninstall the package, the package folder will be also deleted. You can check the behavior of removing a package for details: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console#removing-a-package. There isn't any way to change this as I know.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: This is a big problem. The easiest way I can think of to solve it would be for the NuGet team to add another setting alongside `repositoryPath`, to allow for package persistence upon uninstall (with the default being `delete` for backward compatibility). Would you agree?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: See my answer below just now. You may be interested to know that I was *just about 2.3 seconds* from clicking the button to post a bounty on this one, but my eye caught the red mailbox notice at the top of the screen. That, of course, was you, answering my other question. So you saved me from myself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems I'm discussing a non-issue.

Per a *very* helpful email thread with Yishai on the NuGet team just now, I've realized that the likely reason I'm noticing it just now in VS 2015 is simply because this time I'm watching the `Uninstall-Package` output where before I wasn't.

The bottom line is that even when a package is deleted during uninstall, Package Restore pulls it out of cache the next time a solution needs it.

You may be interested in a blog Yishai pointed out to me:

https://oren.codes/2016/02/08/project-json-all-the-things/

I was briefly considering going down that path until all of the dots connected on this. But it's a great reference nonetheless—definitely one to keep handy.

All that said, I've posted over at [GitHub/NuGet/Issues](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2780) in case you'd like to follow it.