# How to generate a *.NUSPEC file during a VSTS build?

Tags: vb.net, azure-devops, nuspec, azure-artifacts

Currently the NuGet Packager VSTS Build Step seems to not support *.VBPROJ files, so it looks like the only alternative will be to use *.NUSPEC files.

However, I'm unfamiliar with how to automatically create a *.NUSPEC file on the server at build time.

Is this a problem that other VB developers have solved somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you can use vbproj file to generate nuget package with "NuGet Packager" task, it can work:

[image]

And for your question, the nuspec file can be generated from the vbproj file or dll file of your build output by run "nuget spec" command, so you can add a "Command Line" task in your build definition to call nuget command to do this as following:
[image]
You can also change "spec" to "pack" to generate nuget package file from the command directly. Refer to this link for details: [Creating and Publishing a Package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package).

Comment: Eddie, this is good news. I believe I'm going to prefer the former, in the interests of keeping things simple—I wasn't aware that the VSTS Build Step could support *.VBPROJ files directly. So then is it just a matter of specifying the *.VBPROJ filename in the dialog that asks for a *.CSPROJ file?

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Eddie, could you have a look at my other NuGet question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37106930)—I'm having a dickens of a time with VS 2015's new behavior in this regard. I'm interested in your opinion.